# Ratio between Expected Shortfall and Value at Risk for $t$-distribution

Tags: value-at-risk

If $X$ is a random variable with $t$-distribution of parameter $\mathcal{v}$, how can I prove that
$$
\lim_{\alpha \to 1^{-}} \frac{\mathrm{ES}_{\alpha}(X)}{\mathrm{VaR}_{\alpha}(X)} = \frac{\mathcal{v}}{\mathcal{v}-1}?
$$
In the book *Quantitative Risk Management: Concepts, Techniques and Tools* by Alexander J. McNeil  et al., I found the following formulas: 
$$\mathrm{ES}_{\alpha} = \frac {g_v(t_v^{-1}(\alpha))}{1- \alpha} \frac{v+(t_v^{-1}(\alpha))^2}{v-1}
,\qquad\mathrm{VaR}_{\alpha} = t_v^{-1}(\alpha)$$
where $t_v$ denotes the distribution function of the standard student and $g_v$ the density function of the same distribution.
But I'm having dificulties evaluating such limit. Any suggestions?

Comment: googling "value at risk student" and "expected shortfall student" gives some useful info.

Comment: @AlexC I could find any useful info, could you be more specific?

Comment: Read the following link at pag. 7 and then compute $Var_{\alpha}(X)$ for a t distribution: http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~saralees/chap17.pdf  . Try also pag. 10 here: http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/bs41202/sp2011/lec9-11.pdf

Comment: Vandalizing questions is not allowed.

Answer (score 4):

Let $u=t^{-1}_v(\alpha)$ and recall that $g_v(u)=c_v(v+u^2)^{-\frac{v+1}2}$ for some constant $c_v$. By the formulas you provided,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\lim_{\alpha\to 1^-}\frac{\mathrm{ES}_\alpha(X)}{\mathrm{VaR}_\alpha(X)}&=&\lim_{\alpha\to 1^-} \frac{g_v(t^{-1}_v(\alpha))}{(1-\alpha)(v-1)\left(\frac{t^{-1}(\alpha)}{v+(t^{-1}(\alpha))^2}\right)}\\
=\lim_{u\to\infty} \frac{g_v(u)}{(1-t_v(u))(v-1)\left(\frac{u}{v+u^2}\right)}&=&\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{(v+u^2)^{-(v-1)/2}u^{-1}c_v/(v-1)}{(1-t_v(u))}.\end{eqnarray*}$$
This is of the form $[0/0]$. L'Hopital's rule gives
$$\frac{\frac{d}{du}\left[(v+u^2)^{-(v-1)/2}u^{-1}c_v/(v-1)\right]}{-g_v(u)}=\frac{c_v}{v-1}\frac{\frac{d}{du}\left[(v+u^2)^{-(v-1)/2}u^{-1}\right]}{-g_v(u)}$$
$$=\frac{c_v}{v-1}\frac{\left[-\frac{v-1}2(v+u^2)^{-(v+1)/2}2uu^{-1}+(v+u^2)^{-(v-1)/2}(-u^{-2})\right]}{-c_v(v+u^2)^{-(v+1)/2}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{v-1}\left[\frac{v-1}1+(v+u^2)(u^{-2})\right]=1+\frac{v+u^2}{(v-1)u^2}\to1+0+\frac1{v-1}=\frac{v}{v-1},$$
as desired.